# set separate grid for two different frames

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want a window that contains two frames. The top frame includes five labels for user input. The bottom frame includes two buttons. I got this result:

[image]

It is obvious that the button location is wrong. It seems to me that the button's grid does not work.

Here is my code:

```
frame1 = Frame(master).grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
frame2 = Frame(master).grid(row=1, sticky="ew")

Label(frame1, text="game name").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(frame1, text="env").grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(frame1, text="event_source").grid(row=2, column=0)
Label(frame1, text="event_name").grid(row=3, column=0)
Label(frame1, text="game_id").grid(row=4, column=0)

e1 = Entry(frame1).grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = Entry(frame1).grid(row=1, column=1)
e3 = Entry(frame1).grid(row=2, column=1)
e4 = Entry(frame1).grid(row=3, column=1)
e5 = Entry(frame1).grid(row=4, column=1)

Button(frame2, text='Quit', command=master.destroy).grid(row=0, column=0)
Button(frame2, text='Save', command=lambda: self.show_entry_fields(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5)).grid(row=0, column=3)
```

Comment: Try printing the value of `frame1` and `frame2`. They aren’t what you think they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be defining the grid details on the same line you define the frame.

```
frame1 = Frame(master).grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
```

returns `None` to `frame1`.

Instead write it as

```
frame1 = Frame(master)
frame1.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
```

This goes for the rest of your labels and frames as well. Best practice to always define it separately,  even if it sometimes looks like you can get away with it.

Comment: Solved. Thank you.